# How can I extract localized string resources for translation?

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have several Visual Studio 2008 projects (ASP.NET 3.5) with many local resource files for localization of strings found in specific ASP.NET pages. Some of them are grouped in folders, some are named based on the page they are localizing, etc.

For example, App_LocalResources folder has a list of .resx files matching ASPX pages, UserControls/App_LocalResources matching ASCX user controls, etc.

Now I need to translate the application to another language and I would like to send all those keys for translation to someone who doesn't have access to the Visual Studio projects.

I could always write a small console app which would recursively find all .resx files and combine them to one big custom XML file which I could then send for translation. Upon receiving the translated XML file, the console app would recreate all small .resx files.

This all isn't a problem, but there must be a better way. What would you suggest, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently adding .NET support to [appTranslator](http://www.apptranslator.com) to .NET. The tool helps you easily manage translations of your resources by letting translators work on a single localization project file and creating the satellite DLLs right-away from the translations. I'll let you know when it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

[Passolo](http://www.passolo.com) will automatically extract the default resource strings from exe's and dll's to a "bundle" that you can pass to a translation firm.

We are doing this at my work and it seems to work quite well.

You can exclude/hide strings to translate, add comments for each string and have multiple languages in the same project/bundle.

=======================

This Visual Studio Add in helps extract individual strings to resource files (.resx)

http://resourcerefactoring.codeplex.com/

*Resource Refactoring Tool provides developers an easy way to extract hard coded strings from the code to resource files.*

Its says its only been developed for VS 2005/2008 but it will be updated for vs 2010 soon.

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script for extracting all files into an excel. After extracting into excel any can easily manipulate it easily or write a tool for converting resource files to excel.

For Reference:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20920/NET-Resource-File-to-Excel-File-Converter